# Auth0 refresh access token causes popup on iOS

Tags: ios, access-token, auth0

At one point in my app, I need to refresh the access token to reflect changes that have happened to the account. On iOS, the system dialog is displayed:

```
"myApp" Wants to Use "mySite.com" to Sign In
This allows the app and website to share information about you.
Cancel / Continue
```

Tapping on `Continue` shows the Auth0 login screen briefly, and then it silently logs in without user interaction. Is there a way to refresh the access token without showing this system dialog?

This is how I am refreshing the access token:

```
static func attemptAuthentication() {
    let params = someParametersForAnalytics()
    Auth0
        .webAuth(bundle: bundler)
        .scope("openid profile email offline_access")
        .audience("mySite")
        .parameters(Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: params))
        .start {
            switch $0 {
            case .failure(let error):
                authenticationFailed(error:error)
            case .success(let credentials):
                authenticationSucceeded(credentials: credentials, manually: true)
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: You probably want to call https://auth0.github.io/Auth0.swift/Protocols/Authentication.html#/s:5Auth014AuthenticationP5renew16withRefreshToken5scopeAA7RequestVyAA11CredentialsCAA0B5ErrorVGSS_SSSgtF

Comment: This works, but exactly the same as my function above, in that the system dialog appears, which needs to be accepted before it ~silently logs in. One difference from the docs though, I had to add a `.authentication()` to the Auth0 command, otherwise it would not compile. Is it something I did wrong, or are the docs incorrect?

Comment: That doesn't sound right. A `renew` should use an available refresh token and succeed or fail silently. The [sample code](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/auth0-swift/auth0-swift-save-and-renew-tokens) shows an `authentication` in the chain.  Did you accidentally include a `webAuth`?

Comment: @Paulw11 - I'm not 100% sure how I fixed this, but I think you may have been right, that I was inadvertently including a webAuth in the flow I had created. Thanks